# Laravel 5 fetch huge mysql data dynamically to jquery-datatable

Tags: php, mysql, datatables, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2/Mysql as backend and jquery-datatable in frontend. I need to fetch huge amount of records from mysql database to Jquery-datable. I checked and found that there is a dynamic way of listing data [here](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/defer_loading.html)

but this fetch records directly from single table to the view and I need to fetch records from three different tables with join. Is there any other option/way to fetch records dynamically (dynamic pagination) to the Datatable with joining multiple tables using Laravel.

Comment: Not being familiar with the exact format that datatable requires I can't say exactly what it is you need to do but the idea would be to gather all results using the query builder and then return them as JSON. The example that datatables offers is not very helpful there.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Eloquent documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading, specially the `with` method.

Also, in order to paginate you can use the `->paginate(num_records)`
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination

Comment: Yes I can do it with Laravel easily but I have to do it with Jquery-Datables.

Comment: But you need to provide the API on the backend to fetch the data on the frontend. You need to create a rest method like GET records/from/to or records/page. based on that, the Backend will fetch the info from the database, eager loading the nested relationships and serialize to Json.